# Cant fetch the ID of dynamically created Textboxes. Any solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to get the ID of dynamically generated textboxes. Hence I cant get their values. Posting my code below . Please help .

```
protected void txt_Freq_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try

        {

            int rem = Convert.ToInt16(ddl_freq.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
            Table tbl1 = new Table();
            form1.Controls.Add(tbl1);
            for (i = 1; i <= rem; i++)
            {

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "rem" + i.ToString();
                Label lb = new Label();
                CalendarExtender calex = new CalendarExtender();
                calex.ID = "calexRem" + i.ToString();
                calex.TargetControlID = "rem" + i.ToString();
                DropDownList txt_Time_rem = new DropDownList();
                txt_Time_rem.ID = "ddl" + i.ToString();


                for (int hr = 0; hr <= 23; hr++)
                {
                    for (int min = 0; min < 60; min += 15)
                    {
                        if (hr <= 9 && min == 0)
                            txt_Time_rem.Items.Add(new ListItem('0' + hr.ToString() + ':' + '0' + min.ToString()));
                        else if (hr <= 9 && min != 0)
                            txt_Time_rem.Items.Add(new ListItem('0' + hr.ToString() + ':' + min.ToString()));
                        else if (hr > 9 && min == 0)
                            txt_Time_rem.Items.Add(new ListItem(hr.ToString() + ':' + '0' + min.ToString()));
                        else
                            txt_Time_rem.Items.Add(new ListItem(hr.ToString() + ':' + min.ToString()));
                    }
                }

                txt_Time_rem.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Time"));

                lb.Text = "Reminder " + i.ToString();

                cell.Controls.Add(lb);

                 cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                 cell.Controls.Add(calex);
                cell.Controls.Add(txt_Time_rem);



                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                tbl1.Rows.Add(row);
                Response.Write(tb.ID);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }


    }

 protected void btntemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        for(x=1;x<=Convert.ToInt16(ddl_freq.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());x++)
        {
            TextBox txtUserName = form1.FindControl("rem"+x.ToString()) as TextBox;

            if (txtUserName != null)
            {
                Response.Write("ID found!");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Failed");
            }
```

I have tried replacing form1 with Page.Master as I have a Master Page but nothing works. It will print "Failed". Please Help.

Comment: Your `FindControl` method seems returning null after `as` operator, note that text boxes generated dynamically need to be recreated on postback. Can you see any generated textboxes when previewing aspx page in browser?

Comment: yes , textboxes do appear.

Comment: From my view, seems that you trying to call `FindControl` on entire page instance, thus it only finding through immediate children of the page. You need to wrap generated textboxes on a parent server-side control then execute `FindControl` against that parent control.

Comment: On postback dynamically created control lost their state, the solution is to save the state of those controls into session before page postback and later retrieve the control state from session.